# Проблема Ошибка 007053. Client secret wrong. ЕСИА

Tags: авторизация, oauth2, аутентификация, есиа, госуслуги

При попытке авторизации через Госуслуги выдает ошибку Client secret wrong(Код ошибки: 007053) с использованием endpoint ".../ac".

Подписываю запрос с помощью скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash

cryptcp -signf -dir "/import" -der -strict -cert -detached -thumbprint "$1" -pin "$2" "/import/message" > /dev/null 2>&1
signResult=$?
if [ "$signResult" != "0" ]; then
  exit $signResult
fi
```

Проверяю подпись командой:

```
cryptcp -vsignf -detached -dir ./import ./import/message
```

И получаю результат:

```
CryptCP 5.0 (c) "Crypto-Pro", 2002-2021.
Command prompt Utility for file signature and encryption.

The following certificate will be used:
RDN:********************, **************, **********, *************, ******************************, *******, "ул. ******, дом ***", ***********, RU
Valid from 17.04.2023 08:49:00 to 10.07.2024 08:49:00

Certificate chains are checked.
Folder './import/':
./import/message... Signature verifying...
Signer: ********************, **************, **********, *************, ******************************, *******, "ул. ******, дом ***", ***********, RU
 Signature's verified.
[ErrorCode: 0x00000000]
```

Судя по результату проверки подписание корректное.

Используемый сертификат заказчик загрузил в данные информационной системы. Но почему-то ЕСИА не хочет принимать подписанный запрос.

При подписании сообщения clien_secret имеет длину в ~4000 символов:

```
MIIM6gYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIM2zCCDNcCAQExDDAKBggqhQMHAQECAjALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGgggioMIIIpDCCCFGgAwIBAgIRAOuKpwD9fZA6tPNWdig26JAwCgYIKoUDBwEBAwIwggFXMSAwHgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhF1Y19ma0Byb3NrYXpuYS5ydTEYMBYGA1UECAwPNzcg0JzQvtGB0LrQstCwMRUwEwYFKoUDZAQSCjc3MTA1Njg3NjAxGDAWBgUqhQNkARINMTA0Nzc5NzAxOTgzMDFgMF4GA1UECQxX0JHQvtC70YzRiNC-0Lkg0JfQu9Cw0YLQvtGD0YHRgtC40L3RgdC60LjQuSDQv9C10YDQtdGD0LvQvtC6LCDQtC4gNiwg0YHRgtGA0L7QtdC90LjQtSAxMRkwFwYDVQQHDBDQsy4g0JzQvtGB0LrQstCwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJSVTEuMCwGA1UECgwl0JrQsNC30L3QsNGH0LXQudGB0YLQstC-INCg0L7RgdGB0LjQuDEuMCwGA1UEAwwl0JrQsNC30L3QsNGH0LXQudGB0YLQstC-INCg0L7RgdGB0LjQuDAeFw0yMzA0MTcwODQ5MDBaFw0yNDA3MTAwODQ5MDBaMIIBwDELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxNTAzBgNVBAgMLNCg0LXRgdC_0YPQsdC70LjQutCwINCh0LDRhdCwICjQr9C60YPRgtC40Y8pMS8wLQYDVQQJDCbRg9C7LiDQm9C10YDQvNC-0L3RgtC-0LLQsCwg0LTQvtC8IDEyNjEVMBMGA1UEBwwM0K_QutGD0YLRgdC6MW0wawYDVQQKDGTQnNCY0J3QmNCh0KLQldCg0KHQotCS0J4g0JfQlNCg0JDQktCe0J7QpdCg0JDQndCV0J3QmNCvINCg0JXQodCf0KPQkdCb0JjQmtCYINCh0JDQpdCQICjQr9Ca0KPQotCY0K8pMRgwFgYFKoUDZAESDTEwMzE0MDIwNTc2MTAxFTATBgUqhQNkBBIKMTQzNTA1NDUxODEjMCEGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYUbXp3b3JrMjAxOUB5YW5kZXgucnUxbTBrBgNVBAMMZNCc0JjQndCY0KHQotCV0KDQodCi0JLQniDQl9CU0KDQkNCS0J7QntCl0KDQkNCd0JXQndCY0K8g0KDQldCh0J_Qo9CR0JvQmNCa0Jgg0KHQkNCl0JAgKNCv0JrQo9Ci0JjQrykwZjAfBggqhQMHAQEBATATBgcqhQMCAiQABggqhQMHAQECAgNDAARAEgFChnmvY3vKry8iH7h3lymhFMOQCIiLAwNMUFHyw4fJ5K5pYEhLYnzbAbWER_MvJ6pinFaFR3G1e3riIkWQEKOCBIIwggR-MA4GA1UdDwEB_wQEAwID-DATBgNVHSUEDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDAjATBgNVHSAEDDAKMAgGBiqFA2RxATAMBgUqhQNkcgQDAgEBMCwGBSqFA2RvBCMMIdCa0YDQuNC_0YLQvtCf0YDQviBDU1AgKDQuMC45OTYzKTCCAYkGBSqFA2RwBIIBfjCCAXoMgYfQn9GA0L7Qs9GA0LDQvNC80L3Qvi3QsNC_0L_QsNGA0LDRgtC90YvQuSDQutC-0LzQv9C70LXQutGBIFZpUE5ldCBQS0kgU2VydmljZSAo0L3QsCDQsNC_0L_QsNGA0LDRgtC90L7QuSDQv9C70LDRgtGE0L7RgNC80LUgSFNNIDIwMDBRMikMaNCf0YDQvtCz0YDQsNC80LzQvdC-LdCw0L_Qv9Cw0YDQsNGC0L3Ri9C5INC60L7QvNC_0LvQtdC60YEgwqvQrtC90LjRgdC10YDRgi3Qk9Ce0KHQosK7LiDQktC10YDRgdC40Y8gNC4wDE7QodC10YDRgtC40YTQuNC60LDRgiDRgdC-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-RLilGAsoUfiUr85_CcoYIBQ6SCAT8wggE7MSEwHwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhJkaXRAZGlnaXRhbC5nb3YucnUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMRgwFgYDVQQIDA83NyDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAxGTAXBgNVBAcMENCzLiDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAxUzBRBgNVBAkMStCf0YDQtdGB0L3QtdC90YHQutCw0Y8g0L3QsNCx0LXRgNC10LbQvdCw0Y8sINC00L7QvCAxMCwg0YHRgtGA0L7QtdC90LjQtSAyMSYwJAYDVQQKDB3QnNC40L3RhtC40YTRgNGLINCg0L7RgdGB0LjQuDEYMBYGBSqFA2QBEg0xMDQ3NzAyMDI2NzAxMRUwEwYFKoUDZAQSCjc3MTA0NzQzNzUxJjAkBgNVBAMMHdCc0LjQvdGG0LjRhNGA0Ysg0KDQvtGB0YHQuNC4ggsA8KniiQAAAAAHnjAKBggqhQMHAQEDAgNBAAAbxCK2C2Qlbo76GeVCj8OGIJ-HjhcPiVPe4q8ul9sw5llmwCFDREbQabX6ELbxWFTpQ5ZNzP41u8hg5g7xOeExggQJMIIEBQIBATCCAW4wggFXMSAwHgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhF1Y19ma0Byb3NrYXpuYS5ydTEYMBYGA1UECAwPNzcg0JzQvtGB0LrQstCwMRUwEwYFKoUDZAQSCjc3MTA1Njg3NjAxGDAWBgUqhQNkARINMTA0Nzc5NzAxOTgzMDFgMF4GA1UECQxX0JHQvtC70YzRiNC-0Lkg0JfQu9Cw0YLQvtGD0YHRgtC40L3RgdC60LjQuSDQv9C10YDQtdGD0LvQvtC6LCDQtC4gNiwg0YHRgtGA0L7QtdC90LjQtSAxMRkwFwYDVQQHDBDQsy4g0JzQvtGB0LrQstCwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJSVTEuMCwGA1UECgwl0JrQsNC30L3QsNGH0LXQudGB0YLQstC-INCg0L7RgdGB0LjQuDEuMCwGA1UEAwwl0JrQsNC30L3QsNGH0LXQudGB0YLQstC-INCg0L7RgdGB0LjQuAIRAOuKpwD9fZA6tPNWdig26JAwCgYIKoUDBwEBAgKgggIyMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTIzMDcwNzA1MjcyMVowLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIO1GHoHaO-wK-JnkPMGD5iX1I907-rxskY7dkLlhoJ4SMIIBxQYLKoZIhvcNAQkQAi8xggG0MIIBsDCCAawwggGoMAoGCCqFAwcBAQICBCC4jtcQ1VV0Q55LNo5VxT_5IjUb8Fs5RqFHHFIwhAfnTDCCAXYwggFfpIIBWzCCAVcxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEXVjX2ZrQHJvc2them5hLnJ1MRgwFgYDVQQIDA83NyDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAxFTATBgUqhQNkBBIKNzcxMDU2ODc2MDEYMBYGBSqFA2QBEg0xMDQ3Nzk3MDE5ODMwMWAwXgYDVQQJDFfQkdC-0LvRjNGI0L7QuSDQl9C70LDRgtC-0YPRgdGC0LjQvdGB0LrQuNC5INC_0LXRgNC10YPQu9C-0LosINC0LiA2LCDRgdGC0YDQvtC10L3QuNC1IDExGTAXBgNVBAcMENCzLiDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMS4wLAYDVQQKDCXQmtCw0LfQvdCw0YfQtdC50YHRgtCy0L4g0KDQvtGB0YHQuNC4MS4wLAYDVQQDDCXQmtCw0LfQvdCw0YfQtdC50YHRgtCy0L4g0KDQvtGB0YHQuNC4AhEA64qnAP19kDq081Z2KDbokDAKBggqhQMHAQEBAQRAuYZ6jcgZsLq8mNcbQC11hQT58MH6J1q5HDHNvAfXeA0RsE3Y0XQC5kApBhKM3sPSngW7WxTht4eR8GqnJRt7JA
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Или я не так подписываю строку? Возможно, нужно подписывать тем сертификатом, который отправляли в ЕСИА вместе с заявкой на подключение, а не тем, который заказчик сам добавлял в данные ИС в технологическом портале?